Get CVEs on opensource packages
I am an intern analyzing CVEs (Common Vulnerabilities and Exposures) for various packages. Previously, I relied on the NVD (National Vulnerability Database) from NIST, which was straightforward with tools like cve-bin-tool for data conversion.
To address this, I've experimented with alternatives like osv.dev and the GitHub Advisory Database. Unfortunately, these sources often require precise descriptions, and I'm unable to find CVEs for certain packages as easily as I did with NVD.
I'm considering integrating osv.dev, NVD, and GitHub Advisory Database for a more comprehensive analysis, but I'm unsure if this is the best approach. Additionally, I'm curious about the effectiveness of Wiz for CVE analysis.
Has anyone faced similar challenges and found an effective solution or tool for managing and analyzing CVEs across multiple sources? Any advice or recommendations would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!
